# NodeJs: running spawn process memory usage is growing

Tags: node.js, memory, process, pipe, spawn

I use the follow code to run a PHP script in CLI environment within a nodejs server. 
The script takes the data in stdin performs the calculations and return other data to stdout.

The problem is that to run the script with **child_process.spawn** and pipes to an **increasing memory usage**. So I must to restart the node app every little time.

I would like to keep constant the use of RAM.

In the example I use *cat* command to simulate my php script, but the problem persists, **increasing use of memory** proportional to the number of cycles in setInterval.
And I use *setInterval* to simulate period execution of the script.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var php = spawn('cat');

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    php.stdin.write(++i);
},10);
```

**case #2**
I see a memory leak even with:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var php = spawn('cat');
php.stdout.resume();
php.stderr.resume();

var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  gc && gc();
  console.log(process.memoryUsage());
  console.log(php.stdin.write(''+(++i)));
},1000);
```

executed with: *node --expose-gc --always-compact foo.js*

tested for node both v0.10.28

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the interval. More likely than not `php.stdin.write()` is returning false at some point, which indicates that buffering is taking place because the child process can't keep up. If the write() does return false, you generally should stop writing until you see the 'drain' event emitted on `php.stdin`.

Comment: I using setInterval only for simulate period execution of the script, but the problem persists

Comment: Either way, are you actually checking the return value of `write()` or are you piping instead of manually writing or ?

Comment: you can try the code and using top or htop on linux you can verify that memory of node process is growing

Comment: you might want to report the issue on node's github issue tracker then.

Comment: good idea... I'm tried here: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7666 but the problem persists..